# How to record a mobile app UI running on a virtual device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, screen-recording

I'm trying to record the UI for my mobile app but currently I have no idea how to go about it. The end result should look like this -->  [Link to the app UI](https://github.com/MartinMwiti/Flutter-Apps/blob/master/ecommerce/online_shoppingApp/intro.gif). Where through the clip, I can demonstrate the app UI running on a virtual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video you see is a mockup. Try searching for iphone mockup video or Samsung smartphone mockup video